# VIM search and replace whole word starting with dollar

Tags: search, vim, replace, escaping

How can I search and replace whole words starting with dollar sign ($) in VIM?

I know that `\<word\>` matches the whole word and `\$` escapes the dollar sign for regular search and replace, but using `\<\$word\>` or `\$word\>` only results in **"E486: Pattern not found"**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's easily explained. `$` is normally not a *keyword character*, so the assertion that `\<` provides ("match at the start of a [key]word") cannot be fulfilled.

You can add the `$` (for the current buffer) via

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=$
```

but that also affects motions and may even break syntax highlighting. Better just drop the regexp assertion; `\$word\>` should suffice. If you need to assert that there's only whitespace before it: `\S\@<!\$word\>`